# Hoeitz-Hoadama...I made a mistake

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, mistakes

While studying gemorrah Brachos - the following was unclear to me:

When a person makes a hoadama brocha, when he was supposed to make an hoeitz (ex. he wants to eat an apple), he either simply blurted out the worng brocha or even thought he should make a hoadama (example, he thought grapes were hoadama for some reason), and in front of him to eat is also a banana (that he would normally make a hoadama on):

1. Does that first hoadama cover the banana? It was in front of him, but his intent was to make an hoeitz brocha to cover an apple or grapes, not an hoadama fruit.
2. In halacha it seems to imply he has "intention" to eat the other fruit - how do we define that? Does he need to specifically be able to say for certain, before he made the first brocha, that he was going to eat both fruits at that time, **or**, if there is in front of him a whole bunch of fruits (fruits that are hoadama and hoeitz), is that considered "he had in mind" for all those fruits?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! Note that this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends, and consult your rabbi with any practical questions. In your question you say "it seems to imply he has 'intention'", which is unclear to me: did you mean that it seems to imply he **needs** intention, in order for the _b'racha_ to cover the other food? Can you [edit] the question to clarify your intent?

Comment: Generally, we hold that a persons intention covers all relevant food items in front of them when they make a bracha (we only make each bracha once over a whole plate/table of food). Can you clarify why you think that would not be the case here, since the banana is in front of them? Accidentally reciting a "lesser" bracha doesn't change its validity AS a bracha. If you said something like Hamotzi on wine (mixing up shabbos kiddush?)- now THAT would be an interesting question...

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56577

Comment: Also vaguely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57762. | Actually, is the link in my previous comment a duplicate of the OP? ping @IsaacKotlicky

Comment: ^^^ ping @msh210