Wrong Bracha Covers Other Food?
A Bracha made on one food covers anything same Bracha that A) one intends to consume in that sitting, or B) exists on one’s plate or table.
Thus, for example, if I’m sitting at a table with steak and mushrooms, I can make a Bracha (שֶהַּכֹּל) on one mushroom, then take and eat as many mushrooms and steaks as I want without making additional Brachot. I can also bring some more mushrooms from the refrigerator, and eat them without a new Bracha.
Can a Bracha cover food if the intent was directed at something not covered by the Bracha?
For example, if I accidentally said העץ on a cucumber, does that cover any apples on the table that I intend to eat?
What if the apples aren’t yet on the table, but I decide to eat them immediately after making the mistake? Would I have to make a new, correct העץ for the apples?
Does it make a difference if I genuinely thought cucumbers are העץ, or if it was just a slip of the tongue?

I think the answer might be quite straightforward, but for the sake of completeness, can you make the strongest case you can, did you swallow the cucumber, how long before you swallow the apple, etc

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56577/759

@DoubleAA Close, but mine is when the initial food isn’t covered.
