# implicit intent of blessing for unintended items

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, kavana-concentration

What are the main positions and/or halachic consensus regarding the applicability of the appropriate *bracha rishona* (other than "*hamotzi*") originally made on a food item / drink without conscious intent for other food items / drinks that require the same blessing, that are in the same house (though not necessarily the same room), and that he *likely* might eat / drink afterward, but that are not in front of him at the time he made the blessing?  For example, do authorities say, e.g., a "*shehakol*" over a bowl of soup at a dining room table, with only "*stam daas*" (no explicit intent) exempts even a subsequent drink  of water from a kitchen sink?  Does it make a difference if the eater himself goes to the adjacent room vs. a server brings it to the table - assuming we are avoiding the problems of outright *hesech hadaath* / *shinui maqom* (distraction / changing of place, that would terminate the effect of a blessing) e.g. by staying within eyeshot of the  place of blessing?

Comment: What are the assumptions of the situation? Did he have bread? Were the other foods on the table at the time? Etc. There’s literally an entire Siman of Shulchan Aruch dealing with this. Tempted to VTC as too broad.

Comment: @DonielF Amended accordingly.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57762