Making bracha again for same bracha
If I drink water now and say a bracha, and then in a few minutes decide to eat chicken, do I repeat my shehakol?

Because it's a completely different type of food, it would only be covered if you had in mind to eat other types of shehakol. See Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 57:5:

If you say the berachah [Shehakol] over beer, with the intention that
the berachah should exempt all other articles of food that require the
berachah, Shehakol, and then fish is brought [to the table], you need
not repeat the berachah over the fish. [If, however, when saying the
berachah,] you did not think [about any food that might be served
later], then, even if at the time the fish is served there is still
some beer left, you must say the berachah over the fish. This case
cannot be compared to the case of the [different] fruits, where, even
though one of the fruits is an apple and the other nuts, both belong
to the same category of food, whereas, beer and fish are two entirely
different kinds of food, one is food, the other a beverage. [Even
though both require the berachah Shehakol] the one cannot exempt the
other, unless they are both on the table when you recite the berachah,
or you had the intention to exempt it.

If the foods are similar, like different types of meat, Mishnah Berurah 206:22 seems to hold that you can rely on the original bracha as long as the first item is still unfinished:

ומ"מ אם הביאו לו המין האחר בעוד שלא כלה מין הראשון נראה שאין לברך כיון
שהביאו לו בשעה שהיה עסוק עדיין באכילה וכן נראה להלכה

But it's best to explicitly have additional foods in mind. See here and here for more details.

So between beer and fish you need to repeat the bracha if you didn’t have in mind, but between beer and water or some other drink you don’t? How exactly do we define “same category of food”? Is it just liquid vs solid? Would steak and chicken be one category?

Unclear: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57762/6592

Added some clarification. Still not entirely sure about meat and chicken, but it sounds like they would be "similar" by the article's definition. I couldn't find an online copy of the sefer V’Zot HaBracha referenced in footnote 8.

So every time I make a shehakol should I just have in mind and be like “this will cover anything I possibly come to eat”?

Seems that way.

@CuriousYid please CLYOR. That might not work, or it might not be recommended.

@RabbiKaii The Rema recommends it in 206:5.
